# Cannot sort collection by relationship field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a table called `posts` that stores all the post types, each post can have multiple and dynamic meta values, so I have the `post_meta` table which handle all of this.

The `post_meta` table have the following structure:

```
id | post_id |  meta_key | meta_value
```

This is the structure of the `posts` table:

```
id | content | type | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at
```

I need to order the post with the type `section`, so what I did so far is this:

```
$sections = Post::with('meta')->where([
    'type' => 'section',
    'language' => 'it',
    'status' => 'published',
])->get();

$sections->sortBy(function ($sec) {

    return $sec->getMeta('order')->meta_value;
});
```

where `getMeta` is a custom method that I have added within the `Post` model:

```
public function getMeta(string $metaKey)
{
    $key = array_search($metaKey, array_column($this->meta->toArray(), 'meta_key'));
    return $key !== false ? $this->meta[$key] : null;
}
```

The issue is that I doesn't get any ordering, what I'm doing wrong?

Current `datasets`:

```
id | type
 1   section
 2   section
 3   section

id | post_id | meta_key  | meta_value
 1     1        order       0
 2     2        order       2
 3     3        order       1
```

I should get this sequence: `1, 3, 2` instead of `1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `sortBy` on collection you don't modify the existing collection,
so you need to do:

```
$sections = $sections->sortBy(function ($sec) {
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sections = Post::with('meta')->where([
'type' => 'section',
'language' => 'it',
'status' => 'published',
])->get();
```

That Where clousure is not well executed, you need 3 parameteres per array to consult, like this:

```
$sections = Post::with('meta')->where([
['type' '=>' 'section'],
['language' '=>' 'it'],
['status' '=>' 'published'])->get();
```

And i'm not pretty sure what's the query builder you are trying to build because to me it looks like more like an assignation with those arrows.......whatever but at least  you have the correct format now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax of the `where()` clause posted, but yours is completely broken now. `Post::where(['type' => 'section', 'language' => 'it', 'status' => 'published'])->toSql()` generates the correct query `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (\`type\` = ? AND \`language\` = ? AND \`status\` = ?)`. Your query produces the error: `PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ']' or ')'`

Comment: I forgot the last bracket. $sections = Post::with('meta')->where([
['type' '=>' 'section'],
['language' '=>' 'it'],
['status' '=>' 'published']])->get();

Comment: That's still not the issue  `['type' '=>' 'section']` is invalid, you need `,` separators, or `['type' => 'section']`. But, that is still not the issue with this question at all; they get the results from their query, it's the following `sortBy` clause that isn't working.

Comment: Hmmm why don't you try orderBy() directly in the query builder instead of sortBy? could help.

Comment: You're welcome to suggest that as a comment above, but this answer should probably be deleted to avoid more downvotes. Was a good try, but not quite correct.

Comment: Ok delete that. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses